# confused by all the posts on adding a new glib version to ec2 linux

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, glib

I know this question has been asked a thousand times before, because I have read most of the answers and now I am completely lost.

On EC2 AWS AMI

here is my code to build a new glib version

```
wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.47/glib-2.47.4.tar.xz
tar -xJf glib-2.47.4.tar.xz
mkdir /home/_tmp/glib_build
cd /home/_tmp/glib_build
/home/_tmp/glib-2.47.4/configure --prefix=/home/NewBin
make -j ${MAXCORES}
sudo make install
```

All seems to build fine as a lot files end up in `/home/NewBin` and no error in the log.

I then try to build HHVM from source with the following,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/NewBin/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo ldconfig 
cmake -DENABLE_ZEND_COMPAT=ON .
make -j ${MAXCORES}
```

the following error is returned

```
cmake -DENABLE_ZEND_COMPAT=ON .
cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by cmake)
cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by cmake)
+ make -j 40
make: relocation error: /home/_bin/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

if I run the code WITHOUT the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
sudo ldconfig 
cmake -DENABLE_ZEND_COMPAT=ON .
make -j ${MAXCORES}
```

I get the following error

```
cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by cmake)
cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by cmake)
+ make -j 40
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How do I point the `make` to the new glib version?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have 3 distinct problems, none which actually have anything to do with GLIB.

The most serious problem is that you don't understand what you are doing, and "Furious activity is no substitute for understanding".

This error:

```
make: relocation error: /home/_bin/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

is caused by the fact that you have installed a private copy of `libc.so.6` in your `/home/bin/lib`. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains, you need to do quite a bit more if you want to use non-default / non-system `libc.so.6`. In particular, putting `libc.so.6` anywhere on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a *really bad idea(TM)*.

The last problem is this one:

```
cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found ...
```

What this error is telling you is that the version of `cmake` you are invoking has been built with a *later* version of `g++` than the one you have installed. Specifically, `GLIBCXX_4.3.21` [was introduced](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) in gcc-5.1 (and your `cmake` was built with that, or later version of `g++`), but the system `libstdc++.so.6` came from earlier version of GCC.

So, what is the solution?

The easiest approach is to update the *whole* system to a sufficiently new distribution, where all binaries are built against consistent set of system libraries.

If you can't do that, then you need to gain much deeper understanding of what you are doing, and get much more familiar with configuring and building various binaries and libraries that you need. In particular, you should *never* set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and instead add appropriate `--rpath=...` settings *just* for the binaries that require non-system library versions to function.